# Cannot add dynos on Heroku (usingDjango app)

Tags: python, django, heroku, dyno

Struggling to get my app available on Heroku. Which is strange because it used to work.

When querying the error (`heroku logs --tail`), this is what I get

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
```

I searched the problem and looks like I am not running any web dynos.

I therefore, went with the following

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Unfortunately, I then came across the following error message:

```
Scaling dynos... !  !    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

When checking with `heroku ps`, it does say No dynos on "AppName"

The Heroku website advises that this is related to the `Procfile`, which mine seem to be correct:

```
web:gunicorn mysite.wsgi
```

I have removed the buildpacks as suggested using

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
```

I retried to add some dynos, but still no luck.

Would anyone be able to know tell me what I am doing wrong here? Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a space after `web:` in your `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi
```

The [general format is](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format):

```
<process type>: <command>
```